# What does that means "./gradlew assembleDebug"

Tags: android, gradle, task

I have one query regarding gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...

    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        println("task.name = " + task.name);
    }
}
...
```

**build.gradule(Module)**

When I build android application with command line, I can see below

```
my@my:~/Test$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
...

> Configure project :app
task.name = prepareLintJar
task.name = prepareLintJarForPublish
task.name = createMockableJar
task.name = connectedAndroidTest
task.name = deviceAndroidTest
task.name = test
task.name = assembleDebug
task.name = bundleDebug
task.name = preDebugBuild
task.name = generateDebugSources
task.name = generateDebugResources
task.name = generateDebugAssets
task.name = compileDebugSources
task.name = extractDeepLinksDebug
task.name = writeDebugModuleMetadata
task.name = writeDebugApplicationId
task.name = reportBuildArtifactsDebug
task.name = checkDebugManifest
task.name = createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
task.name = processDebugManifest
task.name = generateDebugResValues
task.name = compileDebugRenderscript
task.name = mergeDebugResources
task.name = mergeDebugShaders
task.name = compileDebugShaders
task.name = mergeDebugAssets
task.name = generateDebugBuildConfig
task.name = processDebugResources
task.name = bundleDebugResources
task.name = processDebugJavaRes
task.name = compileDebugAidl
task.name = mergeDebugJniLibFolders
task.name = mergeDebugNativeLibs
task.name = generateDebugFeatureMetadata
task.name = validateSigningDebug
task.name = signingConfigWriterDebug
task.name = javaPreCompileDebug
task.name = compileDebugJavaWithJavac
task.name = bundleDebugClasses
task.name = mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles
task.name = mergeDebugJavaResource
task.name = checkDebugDuplicateClasses
task.name = dexBuilderDebug
task.name = mergeExtDexDebug
task.name = mergeProjectDexDebug
task.name = mergeLibDexDebug
task.name = stripDebugDebugSymbols
task.name = packageDebug
task.name = installDebug
task.name = uninstallDebug
task.name = lintDebug
task.name = generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps
task.name = buildDebugPreBundle
task.name = parseDebugIntegrityConfig
task.name = packageDebugBundle
task.name = signDebugBundle
task.name = makeApkFromBundleForDebug
task.name = packageDebugUniversalApk
task.name = extractApksForDebug
task.name = zipApksForDebug
task.name = assembleDebugAndroidTest
task.name = preDebugAndroidTestBuild
task.name = generateDebugAndroidTestSources
task.name = generateDebugAndroidTestResources
task.name = generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
task.name = compileDebugAndroidTestSources
task.name = processDebugAndroidTestManifest
task.name = generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
task.name = compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
task.name = compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
task.name = generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
task.name = processDebugAndroidTestResources
task.name = bundleDebugAndroidTestResources
task.name = processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes
task.name = compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs
task.name = javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest
task.name = compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
task.name = bundleDebugAndroidTestClasses
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestGeneratedProguardFiles
task.name = mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource
task.name = checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses
task.name = dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest
task.name = mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest
task.name = mergeProjectDexDebugAndroidTest
task.name = mergeLibDexDebugAndroidTest
task.name = validateSigningDebugAndroidTest
task.name = signingConfigWriterDebugAndroidTest
task.name = packageDebugAndroidTest
task.name = installDebugAndroidTest
task.name = uninstallDebugAndroidTest
task.name = connectedDebugAndroidTest
task.name = assembleDebugUnitTest
task.name = preDebugUnitTestBuild
task.name = generateDebugUnitTestSources
task.name = generateDebugUnitTestResources
task.name = generateDebugUnitTestAssets
task.name = compileDebugUnitTestSources
task.name = processDebugUnitTestJavaRes
task.name = javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest
task.name = compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac
task.name = bundleDebugUnitTestClasses
task.name = testDebugUnitTest
task.name = assembleRelease
task.name = bundleRelease
task.name = preReleaseBuild
task.name = generateReleaseSources
task.name = generateReleaseResources
task.name = generateReleaseAssets
task.name = compileReleaseSources
task.name = extractDeepLinksRelease
task.name = writeReleaseModuleMetadata
task.name = writeReleaseApplicationId
task.name = reportBuildArtifactsRelease
task.name = checkReleaseManifest
task.name = createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
task.name = processReleaseManifest
task.name = generateReleaseResValues
task.name = compileReleaseRenderscript
task.name = mergeReleaseResources
task.name = mergeReleaseShaders
task.name = compileReleaseShaders
task.name = mergeReleaseAssets
task.name = generateReleaseBuildConfig
task.name = processReleaseResources
task.name = bundleReleaseResources
task.name = processReleaseJavaRes
task.name = compileReleaseAidl
task.name = mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
task.name = mergeReleaseNativeLibs
task.name = generateReleaseFeatureMetadata
task.name = signingConfigWriterRelease
task.name = javaPreCompileRelease
task.name = compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
task.name = bundleReleaseClasses
task.name = mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles
task.name = mergeReleaseJavaResource
task.name = checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
task.name = dexBuilderRelease
task.name = mergeExtDexRelease
task.name = mergeDexRelease
task.name = stripReleaseDebugSymbols
task.name = packageRelease
task.name = uninstallRelease
task.name = lintVitalRelease
task.name = lintRelease
task.name = generateReleaseFeatureTransitiveDeps
task.name = buildReleasePreBundle
task.name = collectReleaseDependencies
task.name = parseReleaseIntegrityConfig
task.name = packageReleaseBundle
task.name = signReleaseBundle
task.name = configureReleaseDependencies
task.name = sdkReleaseDependencyData
task.name = makeApkFromBundleForRelease
task.name = packageReleaseUniversalApk
task.name = extractApksForRelease
task.name = zipApksForRelease
task.name = assembleReleaseUnitTest
task.name = preReleaseUnitTestBuild
task.name = generateReleaseUnitTestSources
task.name = generateReleaseUnitTestResources
task.name = generateReleaseUnitTestAssets
task.name = compileReleaseUnitTestSources
task.name = processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes
task.name = javaPreCompileReleaseUnitTest
task.name = compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac
task.name = bundleReleaseUnitTestClasses
task.name = testReleaseUnitTest
task.name = androidDependencies
task.name = signingReport
task.name = analyzeDebugDependencies
task.name = analyzeDebugAndroidTestDependencies
task.name = analyzeDebugUnitTestDependencies
task.name = analyzeReleaseDependencies
task.name = analyzeReleaseUnitTestDependencies
task.name = bundle
```

As you can see above, when we type ./gradlew assembleDebug, my tasks are added.

Where can I find the definitions of those commands? (eg. prepareLintJar ..)
Who added those tasks? I just typed assembleDebug task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Kang, Please check these articles on gradle tasks, you may find it helpful:
1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/249-gradle-tutorial-for-android-getting-started#toc-anchor-008
2. https://blog.mindorks.com/building-android-applications-with-gradle-tutorial